# Android R.java neither generated nor updated

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file, ubuntu-14.04

I've tried and searched a lot to solve the problem but didn't succeed at all.

The R.Java file doesn't exist when I make a new project -when the project is very clean-
So I tired importing an old project which had no problem , The R file was there but when I change an XML file the R -unfortunately- doesn't update And it was removed as I cleaned the project.

-When I work with android studio the R is generated and updated with no problem but I want to work with Eclipse now-

Summary:

-I've cleaned the project

-I've re-installed The whole operating system.

-It seems that Eclipse can't generate or modify The R file.

-There isn't a strange package imported (I mean android.R)

-I'm working with Ubuntu 14.04 , Java 8 and Eclipse Luna 4.4.

-There is no problem in the resources.

Thanks in advance :)

### -What solved my problem:

INSTALLING SOME PACKAGES FROM THE SDK MANAGER ESPECIALLY ANDROID SDK BUILD-TOOLS

Comment: Double-check that none of your XML files have errors.

Comment: What the error log says? What is the error

Comment: I've checked them but the problem was missing android sdk build-tools :)

Comment: I am having the same problem. Please let me know how many and which  revisions of Android SDK build-tools do I need to download, as I am having around 10-12 revisions. I downloaded revisions - 21.1.1 and 17, but still not working. please help me out

Answer (score 1):

**`Possibilities for this Error`**::

- `R.java` will not be generated if you have any errors in `manifest`
  or the `xml` files
- Some resources you might have used in `xml` files which does not
  exist anymore

---

**`Solution`**::

- Resolve those `dependencies` errors and double check the `xml-files`
- `Clean` and `run` the project once again

Comment: What errors in manifest or xml files, and how should a beginner recognise them?  Are they marked as errors or warnings by Android studio or Eclipse?

Comment: Your solution works with so many cases but in my case the project is very clean :D I solved it by installing some packages from the SDK manager.


Maybe Android SDK Build-tools was the missed one.

Comment: @SList ..... Sometimes when the XML has errors .... they won't point error ....... Instead only the project folder shows error .... in such cases R.java won't be generated(Eclipse) ..... !

Answer (score 1):

In such cases try cleaning your project or switch workspace if nothing works!
Try this:

1. Disable Auto building from Project Menu in Eclipse.
2. Delete gen folder from your project.
3. Right click on your project and select build project.
   Hope this works!
   Good Luck.

Comment: This works with many people but I hadn't had The build tools =D